# Stuck on a machine for pen-testing learning, possible sudo exploit?

Tags: python, linux, bash, sudo, penetration-testing

I'm struggling with a machine (it's intended to be used for pen-testing training, it has been given by the university professor).

I've got a foothold into the machine and I've passed from `www-data` to `developer`, and there is another user called `jamal` with clearly important information to get `root`, who's the objective of the study.

I managed to find a folder `/opt/scripts` where there two files, `utils.sh` and `backup.py`. I can't edit neither of them since I don't have privileges (even the folder is protected).

Besides, I've sudo permission on `utils.sh` like this:

```
Matching Defaults entries for developer on app4:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User developer may run the following commands on app4:
    (jamal) SETENV: NOPASSWD: /opt/scripts/utils.sh
```

So I think I can use the program for getting into jamal. For what I tried, creating another `echo` in another folder with a reverse shell, changing the `$PATH` and then run it whit `sudo -E` doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

Here's the code for utils and backup:

**utils.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

view_users()
{
    /usr/bin/w
}

view_crontab()
{
    /usr/bin/crontab -l
}


backup_web()
{
    if [ "$EUID" -eq 1001 ]
    then
        echo "Running backup script..."
        /opt/scripts/backup.py &
    else
        echo "Insufficient privileges."
    fi
}


# Non-interactive way
if [ $# -eq 1 ]
then
    option=$1
    case $option in
        1) view_users ;;
        2) view_crontab ;;
        3) backup_web ;;

        *) echo "Unknown option." >&2
    esac

    exit 0
fi


# Interactive way, to be called from the command line
options=("View logged in users"
         "View crontab"
         "Backup web data"
         "Quit")

echo
echo "[[[ System Administration Menu ]]]"
PS3="Choose an option: "
COLUMNS=11
select opt in "${options[@]}"; do
    case $REPLY in
        1) view_users ; break ;;
        2) view_crontab ; break ;;
        3) backup_web ; break ;;
        4) echo "Bye!" ; break ;;

        *) echo "Unknown option." >&2
    esac
done

exit 0
```

**backup.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from shutil import make_archive

src = '/var/www/html/'

dst = '/tmp/backup'

make_archive(dst, 'gztar', src)
```

PS: the file that backup.py create doesn't contain anything useful: it's all information I already got.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Become root? Have you discussed this with Jamal and/or the owner of the machine?

Comment: Please add some details which clarify that what you are trying to do is not intentionally prevented in your environment. This is important, because if it is not about you not knowing how and instead a situation of you not being meant to, then any possible solution might fail - and intentionally so.

Comment: It's a deliberately vulnerable machine for training, I'll add this in the text of the question

Comment: @Yunnosh I don't understand what you're trying to say. English is not my motherlanguage

Comment: It is fine. You already answered with "intentionally vulnerable machine for training". And now I can admit that I politely accused you of asking for help with a malicious attack. Seems a reasonably plausible honest learning now. However, I recommend to try your best to make that as plausible as possible, because many users are extremely careful with not helping the black-hat people here. ;-)

Comment: @Yunnosh okay :) Anyway, if a black-hat was stuck in a machine like this one (that's meant to be easy-medium) it would be quite a disappointing black-hat ahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks dangerous to me:

```
    (jamal) SETENV: NOPASSWD: /opt/scripts/utils.sh
            ^^^^^^^
```

Your user `developer` can run `/opt/scripts/utils.sh` as Jamal, but also choose all environment variables while that script is being run. `sudoers(5)` explicitly warns about this:

> Additionally, environment variables set on the command line are not subject to the restrictions imposed by env_check, env_delete, or env_keep.  As such, only trusted users should be allowed to set variables in this manner.

How is that a vulnerability? `utils.sh` only executes commands using absolute paths and functions from its local scope, so an exploit using the `PATH` variable is out of the question. However, there are several other options.

Preloading a library with [`LD_PRELOAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick#426260) is one way: the library is loaded as soon as a shell is started to run `utils.sh`. You can compile your own dynamic library with initialization code that does whatever you need.

An even easier approach is to exploit [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) to provide your own `shutil.py` module, with an implementation of `make_archive` that contains your payload.

The exact implementation is left as an exercise to the reader ;)

Comment: Thanks! The answer is very clear and I'll try do to what you said :)